# Javascript .match - exclude?

Tags: javascript

I have the loop below.

I need to pull all the names (`lskey`) that does not have include the letter `p` in it, but my attempt is not working.

```
for(var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    var lsKey = localStorage.key(i);
    var lsValue = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));
    if(lsKey.match("^p")) {
        $("#appendedLS").append("<input type='hidden' name='" + lsKey + "' value='" + lsValue + "'/>");
    }
}
```

If any one has answer, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So close!  Inside of a character class the `^` means negation, but outside it means "beginning of string".

The following should work:

```
if(lsKey.match("p") === null){
```

Just check for the character `p`, if it doesn't exist then `match()` will return `null`.

---

That said, if you don't need to use regular expressions then it's much simpler to use the [`indexOf`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) method instead:

```
if(lsKey.indexOf("p") == -1){
```

Answer (score 0):

The indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string.

This method returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs.

```
if(lsKey.indexOf("p")==-1){
        //statement}
```